# Allow dragging when MetroDialog is shown using MahApps

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm using MahApps to create my WPF application. I just figured out, that the MainWindow (MetroWindow class) isn't draggable aslong a MetroDialog is shown.
Is there a way to change this?
I'm calling the dialog from a ViewModel like shown below:

```
var _dialog = new CustomDialog() { Title = "MyDialog" };
\\Content for the dialog..
await _dialogCoordinator.ShowMetroDialogAsync(this, _dialog);
```

I already set the MainWindow to `IsWindowDraggable= "true"`.
Let me know if more information are needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialog windows are always block parent until closed. If you want to drag the parent, you'll need to use regular child window, not the dialog one

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. So there is no way to bypass this? Then I need to switch to SimpleChildWindow instead. Thanks again!

Comment: Well, by design, a model dialog blocks the parent window until user interacts with it. Yes, you need to switch to a  different child window, not the dialog one

Comment: Yes, `MahApps.Metro.SimpleChildWindow` should be fine. Does it answer your question?